# How to replace localhost in emails with correct domain for django reset password?

Tags: django, waitress

I am serving a django app with a reverse proxy via nginx. The app runs locally under localhost:8686 which is mapped to example.com. So the correct link to reset a password would be something like:

```
https://example.com:8686/accounts/reset/MQ/591-05377c39db92f2d5368a/
```

but this is what appears in the emails:

```
https://localhost:8686/accounts/reset/MQ/591-05377c39db92f2d5368a/
```

Obviously, django (locally served with waitress) does not know about the domain name. Is it possible to tell django which domain name it should be using?

Comment: Please show your code and email templates

Comment: I using the standard templates.

Comment: As I see, there is no standard template 'registration/password_reset_email.html' in 
`django.contrib.auth.templates`. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L206

Comment: Never mind, I've found it

Answer (score 1):

First way to do what you want is by overriding the default template by creating a custom `registration/password_reset_email.html`:

```
{# yourProject/yourApp/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html #}
{% trans "Please go to the following page and choose a new password:" %}
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://domain.com{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endblock %}
```

Another way to do this is by enabling the "site framework" (see the link #2).

Docs and sources:

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView
2. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/sites/
3. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html
4. https://github.com/django/django/blob/1e429df748867097451bf0b45d1080ae6828d921/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L277